# Match and replace the content of two JSON files

Tags: php, json

I try to match two JSON files with there codes.
So the first file with product informations only have the codes (like GRM) but for my website I need to display the Code Name (GRAMM) behind the Code (stored in the codelist.json).

**First JSON File: product.json**

- with Code "GRM"

```
          "measurement": {
            "grossWeight": 431,
            "grossWeightUom": "GRM",
            "netContent": "400",
            "netContentUom": "MLT",
            "isBasePriceDeclarationRelevant": "TRUE",
            "priceComparison": 400,
            "priceComparisonUom": "MLT",
          }
```

**Second JSON File: codelist.json**

- with Code "GRM" and Code Name "Gramm"

```
        {
            "ID": "M072",
            "Attribut": "Nährwertkennzeichnung: Bezugsgröße Maßeinheit",
            "PROMIS Codelist Name": "PROMIS_NUTRITIONAL_VALUE_REFERENCE_LEVEL",
            "Code": "GRM",
            "Language": "de",
            "Code Name": "Gramm",
        },
```

Already tried php code:

```
                    $filename = 'codes/codelist.json';
                    $codefile = file_get_contents($filename);
                    $codejson = json_decode($codefile);

                    foreach($codejson as $Code) {
                        if($Code->Code == 'GRM') {
                            echo "Code Name";
                        }
                    }
```

or any idea with "StrgReplace"?

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create new array sorted by code for easier later use
foreach($codelist as $key => $value)
{
   $codelistByCode[$value['Code']] = $value;
}

// Print out correct codename (you could make this as a function)
if($product['measurement']['grossWeightUom'] === 'GRM')
{
   echo $codelistByCode['GRM']['Code Name'];
}
```